# Unable to write to /etc/nginx with eb deploy (aws elastic beanstalk NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm on NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk and I'm encountering a weird issue when deploying via `eb deploy`.

My `.ebextensions` folder has a file that should create a file on `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/file_size_proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 25M;
```

But it looks like it's not able to. I tried several things to test this:

- tried writing it to `/tmp` directory and it's able to
- tried to ssh and manually create the file. It can. So my account shouldn't have problems
- tried creating a bash file that will just migrate the file from `/tmp` to `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory. It's unable to migrate the file if run via the `.ebextensions` route. But run the bash file via ssh, it will.

I've hit the wall. Any idea why this is happening, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Somebody posted the RIGHT answer to this question, but he somehow deleted it, or somebody else did. Not sure if it was an illegal answer? :D I'm waiting for him to repost it, but I guess he deleted it intentionally. *

To solve this issue. instead of placing the `nginx` file modification under `.ebextensions`, place it under `.platform`. So, in this case, have the file under:

`.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`

with content...

`client_max_body_size 25M;`

That's it. It worked! This, btw, is not documented elsewhere -- or at least I didn't see it anywhere. I'm not sure why. The original poster mentioned something like a new AWS api release or something. Maybe this is new.

Comment: Yeah, i have added the answer with all details but moderator deleted it without any comments.

Comment: Oh, wow. I wonder why? I don't see any violations in that answer, is there?

Comment: I actually answered the same same answer in some other question. Its against the rule i think. I cannot put that thread here becuase those top listed answers are not applicable for Elastic Beanstalk and it will be difficult for the developers to find my answer. Anyway i am glad you got the answer.

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder what's against the rules. Anyways, thanks. It's a life saver.